# How do I prevent a "Not supported in LINQ to Entities" exception when creating an IPagedList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, linq

I am creating a web application in ASP.NET MVC 5 and will need to obtain some data using a database. Once the data has been obtained, I want to create an `IPagedList` object using it. However, I have found that this functionality generates an exception stating that `Type CurrentSite is not supported in LINQ to Entities`. Conversely, this doesn't happen when only obtaining the data and not creating the IPagedList.

```
public ActionResult GetComputers(int? SiteID)
{
    //This works
    IQueryable<Computer> computers = db.Computers.Where(c => c.CurrentSite.ID == SiteID);

    //This doesn't - It throws the LINQ to Entities exception
    IPagedList<Computer> computers = db.Computers.Where(c => c.CurrentSite.ID == SiteID).ToPagedList(1, 25);
}
```

How can I create an `IPagedList` object using the obtained data without adding a `CurrentSite` column to my database table?

UPDATE:
Here is the logic behind the `CurrentSite` property.

```
public ComputerSites CurrentDeployment
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ComputerSites == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.ComputerSites.Where(cs => DateTime.Now.IsBetween(cs.StartDate, cs.EndDate) && cs.Deleted == false).OrderBy(cs => cs.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

public Site CurrentSite
{
    get
    {
        if (this.CurrentDeployment == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.CurrentDeployment.Site;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does your IPagedList come from?

Comment: Does `db.Computers.Where(c => c.CurrentSite.ID == SiteID).ToList();` work?

Comment: @AdilMammadov I just tried this and got the same error, even when ordering the query.

Comment: You should update your question and post your models. I thing something is wrong with your models.

Comment: I think `ComputerSites` is navigation proeprty. The problem is at this line: `return this.ComputerSites.Where(cs => DateTime.Now.IsBetween(cs.StartDate, cs.EndDate) && cs.Deleted == false).OrderBy(cs => cs.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();`. Entity framework cannot convert it to SQL query

Comment: @AdilMammadov So should I create a different property for obtaining the computer sites that can be converted to SQL? If so, do you recommend any way that I can alter the current line so that it will become compatible?

Comment: I suggest you chanign logic. Your model does not look right.

Answer (score 0):

PagedList uses `Skip` and `Take` internally ([source](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList)).

```
public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> superset, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    return new PagedList<T>(superset, pageNumber, pageSize);
}


public PagedList(IQueryable<T> superset, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    ...................

    // add items to internal list
    if (superset != null && TotalItemCount > 0)
        Subset.AddRange(pageNumber == 1
            ? superset.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).ToList()
            : superset.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()
        );
}
```

In *Linq to Entities* `Skip` is supported only on ordered queries. So you have to order your query to use `IPagedList`:

```
IPagedList<Computer> computers = db.Computers
    .Where(c => c.CurrentSite.ID == SiteID)
    .OrderBy(c => c.CurrentSite.ID) // Or some other property.
    .ToPagedList(1, 25);
```

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: I tried ordering the query as you did in this answer, but I'm still getting the same exception stating that `CurrentSite` isn't supported.

Comment: Then something wrong  with your model. You should provide your models also.

Answer (score 0):

The IQueryable won't throw an exception, because you are simply building an expression and not executing it yet; Linq to Entities doesn't throw an exception yet, because it doesn't know it will hit it yet. Conversely, when you use IPagedList, you are evaluating this expression, which is why the exception is thrown.

Simply put, Linq understands primitive types, but not complex types you have created yourself. While there are a few workarounds, its probably best to encapsulate the logic you are tying to introduce in the CurrentSite within the where statement, if you can. The core problem is that when you have logic within a property, there is no way Linq can compile that in to SQL ready code to interact within your database.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the most effective. It turns out that you can bypass the problem by adding an `AsEnumerable` call to the query, like so.

```
db.Computers.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.CurrentSite.ID == SiteID).ToPagedList(1, 25);
```

It works properly now.

Comment: I did downvote because you don't understand the impact of calling AsEnumerable, which is fetching the entire query.